# A way to move files via shell sequentially?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

The following AppleScript is great for moving a user defined number of files into folders that are created.
If the files are numbered with padding; 001.txt 002.txt 003.txt, then all is well.

But if they are named 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt then the result is 1.txt 10.txt 11.txt are place in the same folder.

Is there a way to move the files via shell that avoids this?

```
    tell application "Finder" to set thisDir to (target of Finder window 1) as string
    set rootDirectory to quoted form of POSIX path of thisDir
    set counTed to (do shell script "ls -1 " & rootDirectory & " | wc -l") as integer
    if counTed is 0 then
        display alert "There are no files in the root of this directory to move."
        return
    end if
    set filesPerFolder to text returned of (display dialog "There are " & counTed & " files in this folder. 
    How many files would you like to move per folder: " default answer "100")
    set fileCount to (do shell script "cd " & rootDirectory & " && i=0;for f in *;do d=$(printf %03d $((i/" & filesPerFolder & "+1)));let i++;mkdir -p $d;mv \"$f\" $d;done")
    set filesLeft to (do shell script "ls -2 " & rootDirectory & " | wc -l") as integer
    if filesLeft is 0 then
        display alert "Completed."
        return
    end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the shell? The Finder has a sort command. So if you want to get a list of files sorted properly as you require, something like this works. Then you just repeat over the sorted list and move any number of files that you wish.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set thisDir to target of Finder window 1
    set theFiles to files of thisDir
    set sortedFiles to sort theFiles by name

    -- do something with sortedFiles
end tell
```

Comment: Finder takes very long if there are many files. Using shell is a lot faster

Comment: I understand your point. You can replace the Finder with System Events for most of this stuff so that would help. I think no matter what, you are going to have to perform a sort of some kind and if that's true then any solution you derive is going to be relatively slow sorting a large amount of files. Good luck though... my answer was just a thought.